# Rails 2 - a good way to realize such scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I have such code in **routes.rb** `in Rails 3` app:

```
  scope 'robokassa' do
    match 'paid'    => 'robokassa#paid',    :as => :robokassa_paid    # to handle Robokassa push request
    match 'success' => 'robokassa#success', :as => :robokassa_success # to handle Robokassa success redirect
    match 'fail'    => 'robokassa#fail',    :as => :robokassa_fail    # to handle Robokassa fail redirect
  end
```

I want to write such scope in `Rails 2` app. What is a correct way to realize that? Does rails 2 support scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in Rails 2.

```
map.resources :robokassa do |robokassa|
  robokassa.match 'success' => 'robokassa#success'
  robokassa.match 'paid' => 'robokassa#paid'
  robokassa.match 'fail' => 'robokassa#fail'
end
```

Or you could separately declare each route like this:

```
map.connect 'robokassa/success', :controller => 'robokassa', :action => 'success'
```

Comment: When i tried your first solution (map.resources) and then a tried to run `$ rake routes` i got `rake aborted! Illegal route: the :controller must be specified!`. Also, second solution works.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I don't remember that anymore, but if all else fails I think you can always do:

```
match 'robokassa/paid' => 'robokassa#paid', :as => :robokassa_paid
```

and so on.